# hide forbidden icon during drag and drop operation within the app

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, reorderlist

I have been using iOS Drag and Drop feature only for reordering tableView Cell.

So, while reordering, a forbidden icon on top right corner in Preview View is being shown.

I want to hide this icon.

How can I do it?
please note that, dropSessionDidUpdate is not being called if you slightly move the cell left or right. and I am using insetGroupedTableView style

[image]