# UITableViewCell drag and drop starts with a Forbidden icon

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, uikit

So, I've been wanting to implement the longpress gesture to re-order cells in a `UITableView`.

However, I noticed that as soon as I longpress a cell and shift it slightly in any direction, there is a Forbidden grey icon in the top-right corner of the cell. As I shift the cell, the forbidden icon remains until the delegate method `tableView(_ tableView:, dropSessionDidUpdate:, withDestinationIndexPath:)` gets called. Then the forbidden icon disappears, and doesn't come back (not even after re-entering the original cell location).

If I completely remove the protocol `UITableViewDropDelegate` from the class declaration (as it appears to not be needed for this whole process to work), the only thing that's different is that the Forbidden icon comes back when re-entering the original cell position. Weird?

I feel like this is not normal, since dropping the cell in the same spot is definitely NOT forbidden (and releasing the longpress allows the cell to return to its position).
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71427402/8845253) from last year, unfortunately it got no answers.

Anyway, this is the code I've got so far:

```swift
//in viewDidLoad(). Also, class declaration includes protocols UITableViewDragDelegate and UITableViewDropDelegate
tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
tableView.dragDelegate = self
tableView.dropDelegate = self

//I left this blank as it prevents all cells from being allowed to be dragged/dropped; leaving it blank seem to force the tableView(_:, canMoveRowAt:) method to be called first and therefore only cells at specified indexPaths are allowed to move
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    //original code
    //let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())
    //dragItem.localObject = myData[indexPath.row]
    //return [dragItem]

    //new code
    return []
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
    if session.localDragSession != nil, tableView.hasActiveDrag, session.items.count == 1
    {
        return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    }

    return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel) //never gets called in tests, which seems expected given the 3 conditions above
}

//NEVER EVEN GETS CALLED (weird?), so I removed it
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    //my logic
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    //my logic
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    //my logic
}
```

On a side note, sometimes after re-ordering a cell, the cell becomes invisible until it goes off-screen (and I assume its `tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt:)` method gets called). I have a few ideas on how to solve this, namely reloading the cell or tableview after a successful move, but I still felt like this shouldn't happen.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps the following gives you a simpler solution to implementing the reorder via drag and drop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270449/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-to-reorder-a-uitableview

Comment: That's the first SO page that I referenced for my own code. I followed every variation that I could think of, but nothing seems to remove the Forbidden icon.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer. Your code is implementing far more than that answer.

Comment: In case you didn't know, there are two "drag-and-drop" solutions in UITableView, in case you didn't know. I had recently needed this feature, and Apple's docs led me to use this API, where I got stuck, just like you. The other one is a lot easier to implement, esp. if it's your first run with ~fancy-tables (my made-up word for the newer table features). +1 @HangarRash.

Comment: What's the other one? (I was trying to move away from the old way Apple did it, aka the re-order control during editing). I mean, the solution I have posted above fully works, the issue is just visual:  the Forbidden icon just won't go away.

Comment: @HangarRash As I said, I tried every combination, so even commenting out the old  methods I had. It's as if the initial Proposal is in a `.forbidden` operation state, and as soon as the session gets an update in `dropSessionDidUpdate`, I can return a `.move` operation (and from that point on the .forbidden icon is gone). Might be a bug that's resolved now; I'm still running Xcode 13.3.1)

Comment: Yup, updating XCode and iOS 16 fixed the icon issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that updating both XCode (to 14.2) and iOS (to 16.3.1), fixed the forbidden icon issue.

I did also learn that, for my use case at least, anything `UITableViewDropDelegate`-related was not needed to achieve simple longpress-to-reorder functionality, and that having the drag delegate's function return the empty array is what makes it work this way.

I have a feeling, however, that the old "reorder" functionality is going to be deprecated at some point in the future (meaning this mix of old functions + the new drag delegate is not going to work) in favor of the whole drag + drop delegates working together.